# How we can differentiate between State and Momento design pattern, whereas both are used for State Preservation..?

Tags: design-patterns

How can one **differentiate between State and Momento design pattern**, whereas **both are used for State Preservation**..?

Comment: `memento` is all about exposing **private state in a immutable opaque object** ( bold part is the most important ). *Undo* is just one narrow use case that it can be used in.

Comment: `state pattern` is about an object's **behavior changing** when its **private internal state** changes. This has nothing to do with *state preservation* and is a pure behavioral pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**Memento Pattern**

Imagine a program that should transmit a file over TCP/IP with FTP. Well, you are not sure that the remote server is available. You will probably implement a proxy between the class that send the message and the class that ask for the file to be sent. If this proxy find out that the remote server is unavailable for the moment, it could possibly ask a keeper to keep it's state in a dedicated memento list without violating the encapsulation (login, password, message, etc). Later, the keeper, running in another thread, could possibly check the list of mementos to be sent and rebirth the proxy(s) that will send the message(s) (or try to). You can adapt this to the publish / subscribe pattern, email sending, etc.

**State Pattern**

Imagine you are writing a game with some kind of mutant superhero. In a certain condition you need to be a human. You use the concrete state needed at that time. Now, imagine you need to become that beast you can be to save the lady you love. Then you get back to the state dedicated to this situation. But, at anytime, you use the same leg, foot, or whatever *object reference* to accomplish your duty.

Comment: both of these are completely wrong analogies

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Please, tell me why !

Comment: see my comments on the question

Comment: @JarrodRoberson where are the differences ? doesn't seems to be really different in the background. Are you arguing for the shape ?